# Convert spaCy `Doc` into CoNLL 2003 sample

Tags: python, nlp, spacy-3, conll

I was planning to [train a Spark NLP custom NER model](https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-ner-with-bert-in-spark-nlp-874df20d1d77), which uses the CoNLL 2003 format to do so (this blog even leaves some [traning sample data](https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp/tree/master/src/test/resources/conll2003) to speed-up the follow-up). This "sample data" is NOT useful for me, as I have my own training data to train a model with; this data however, consists of a list of spaCy [Doc](https://spacy.io/api/doc) objects and quite honestly, I don't know how to carry on with this conversion. I have found three approaches so far, each with some *considerable* weakness:

1. In spaCy's documentation, I have found [an example code](https://spacy.io/universe/project/spacy-conll) about how to build a SINGLE Doc to CoNLL using [`spacy_conll` project](https://github.com/BramVanroy/spacy_conll), but notice it uses a blank spacy model, so it is not clear where "my own labeled data" comes to play; [furthermore](https://github.com/BramVanroy/spacy_conll#in-python), it seems `conll_formatter` component is "added at the end of the pipeline", so it seems "no direct conversion from Doc to CoNLL is actually done"... Is my grasping correct?
2. In Prodigy forum (another product of the same designers of spaCy), I found [this purposal](https://support.prodi.gy/t/ner-format-to-conll/1153), however that "CoNLL" (2003 I suppose?) format seems to be incomplete: the POS tag seems to be missing (which can be easily obtained via [`Token.pos_`](https://spacy.io/api/token#attributes), as well as the *"Syntactic chunk"* (whose spaCy equivalent, does not seem to exist). These four fields are mentioned in [CoNLL 2003 official documentation](https://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/conll2003/ner/#:%7E:text=Spanish%20and%20Dutch.-,Software%20and%20Data,-The%20CoNLL%2D2003).
3. Speaking of a "direct conversion from Doc to CoNLL", I have also found [this](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/5188#issuecomment-602848635) implementation based on `textacy` library, but it seems this implementation got deprecated by version [0.11.0](https://github.com/chartbeat-labs/textacy/blob/main/CHANGES.md#0110-2021-04-12), because *"CONLL-U [...] wasn't enforced or guaranteed"* , so I am not sure whether to use it or not (BTW, the most up-to-date `textacy` implementation when writing these lines, is `0.12.0`)

My current code looks like:

```py
import spacy
from spacy.training import offsets_to_biluo_tags
from spacy.tokens import Span

print("SPACY HELPER MODEL")
base_model = "en_core_web_sm"
nlp = spacy.load(base_model)
to_disable= ['parser', 'lemmatizer', 'ner']
_ = [nlp.remove_pipe(item) for item in to_disable]
print("Base model used: ", base_model)
print("Removed components: ", to_disable)
print("Enabled components: ", nlp.pipe_names)

# Assume text is already available as sentences...
# so no need for spaCy `sentencizer` or similar
print("\nDEMO SPACY DOC LIST BUILDING...", end="")
doc1 = nlp("iPhone X is coming.")
doc1.ents = [Span(doc1, 0, 2, label="GADGET")]
doc2 = nlp("Space X is nice.")
doc2.ents = [Span(doc1, 0, 2, label="BRAND")]
docs = [doc1, doc2]
print("DONE!")

print("\nCoNLL 2003 CONVERSION:\n")
results = []
for doc in docs:
    # Preliminary: whole sentence
    whole_sentence = doc.text
    # 1st item (CoNLL 2003): word
    words = [token.text for token in doc]
    # 2nd item (CoNLL 2003): POS
    pos = [token.tag_ for token in doc]
    # 3rd item (CoNLL 2003): syntactic chunk tag
    sct = ["[UNKNOWN]" for token in doc]
    # 4th item (CoNLL 2003): named entities
    spacy_entities = [
        (ent.start_char, ent.end_char, ent.label_)
        for ent in doc.ents
    ]
    biluo_entities = offsets_to_biluo_tags(doc, spacy_entities)
    results.append((whole_sentence, words, pos, sct, biluo_entities))

for result in results:
    print(
        "\nDOC TEXT (NOT included in CoNLL 2003, just for demo): ",
        result[0], "\n"
    )
    print("-DOCSTART- -X- -X- O")
    for w,x,y,z in zip(result[1], result[2], result[3], result[4]):
        print(w,x,y,z)

# Pending: write to a file, but that's easy, and out of topic.
```

Which gives as output:

```
DOC TEXT (NOT included in CoNLL 2003, just for demo):  iPhone X is coming.

-DOCSTART- -X- -X- O
iPhone NNP [UNKNOWN] B-GADGET
X NNP [UNKNOWN] L-GADGET
is VBZ [UNKNOWN] O
coming VBG [UNKNOWN] O
. . [UNKNOWN] O

DOC TEXT (NOT included in CoNLL 2003, just for demo):  Space X is nice.

-DOCSTART- -X- -X- O
Space NNP [UNKNOWN] B-BRAND
X NNP [UNKNOWN] L-BRAND
is VBZ [UNKNOWN] O
nice JJ [UNKNOWN] O
. . [UNKNOWN] O
```

Have you done something like this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @AlbertoAndreotti's help, I managed to get to a functional workaround:

```py
import spacy
from spacy.training import offsets_to_biluo_tags
from spacy.tokens import Span

print("SPACY HELPER MODEL")
base_model = "en_core_web_sm"
nlp = spacy.load(base_model)
to_disable= ['parser', 'lemmatizer', 'ner']
_ = [nlp.remove_pipe(item) for item in to_disable]
print("Base model used: ", base_model)
print("Removed components: ", to_disable)
print("Enabled components: ", nlp.pipe_names)

# Assume text is already available as sentences...
# so no need for spaCy `sentencizer` or similar
print("\nDEMO SPACY DOC LIST BUILDING...", end="")
doc1 = nlp("iPhone X is coming.")
doc1.ents = [Span(doc1, 0, 2, label="GADGET")]
doc2 = nlp("Space X is nice.")
doc2.ents = [Span(doc1, 0, 2, label="BRAND")]
docs = [doc1, doc2]
print("DONE!")

print("\nCoNLL 2003 CONVERSION:\n")
results = []
for doc in docs:
    # Preliminary: whole sentence
    whole_sentence = doc.text
    # 1st item (CoNLL 2003): word
    words = [token.text for token in doc]
    # 2nd item (CoNLL 2003): POS
    pos = [token.tag_ for token in doc]
    # 3rd item (CoNLL 2003): syntactic chunk tag
    # sct = pos  # Redundant, so will be left out
    # 4th item (CoNLL 2003): named entities
    spacy_entities = [
        (ent.start_char, ent.end_char, ent.label_)
        for ent in doc.ents
    ]
    biluo_entities = offsets_to_biluo_tags(doc, spacy_entities)
    results.append((whole_sentence, words, pos, biluo_entities))

for result in results:
    print(
        "\nDOC TEXT (NOT included in CoNLL 2003, just for demo): ",
        result[0], "\n"
    )
    print("-DOCSTART- -X- -X- O")
    for w,x,y,z in zip(result[1], result[2], result[2], result[3]):
        print(w,x,y,z)
```

As complementary information, I found out that the **3rd** missing item, *"syntactic chunking tag"*, is related to a broader problem called *"phrase chunking"*, that happens to be [an unsolved problem in Computer Science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrase_chunking), for which only aproximations have been got, so regardless of the library used, the conversion of that **3rd** item specifically, into CoNLL 2033, *might* have errors. However, it seems Spark NLP does not care at all about 2nd & 3rd items, so the workaround suggested here, is acceptable.

For more details, you might want to put an eye on this [thread](https://support.prodi.gy/t/prodigy-jsonl-or-spacy-doc-to-conll-2003/6064).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at a sample CoNLL file, you'll see they just separate entries with one blank line between them. So you just use a for loop.

```
for doc in docs:
    for sent in doc.sents:
        print("#", doc) # optional but makes it easier to read
        print(sent._.conll_str)
        print()
```

CoNLL files are split by sentence, not spaCy Doc, but if you don't have sentence boundaries you can just loop over docs. There also seems to be an option to turn on headers directly in the component, see their README.

Comment: Hello @polm23 . I have updated the problem description, and deleted some redundant comments. Please give them a check, and let me know what you think about the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this could help or not, but here's what I can add,

- Spark-NLP NER won't use your POS tags, so if you could just fill them with foo-bar values, that could simplify your work.
- Check JSL Annotation Lab product. It allows you to label data, it smoothly integrates with Spark-NLP NER. It's free.

Comment: Hello @AlbertoAndreotti . Could you please ellaborate with an example of a single training sample? I am confused, since [some authors](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2022/06/how-to-train-an-ner-model-with-huggingface/) skip the 2nd (POS) and 3rd (syntactic chunk tag) items while [others](https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-ner-with-bert-in-spark-nlp-874df20d1d77) copy the 2nd item on the 3rd one... Which is correct, and better yet, what do you do? BTW, I'll check that "JSL Annotation Lab" tagging tool soon, thanks.

Comment: when the NER is based on embeddings, like most of the models these days, embeddings will encode all the syntactic, and POS information themselves, so 2nd and 3rd columns are redundant and not used.
If still the readers of spark-nlp require them, you could probably replace them with dummy values safely.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @AlbertoAndreotti . So basically, how a single CoNLL 2003 sample would look like, is equal to what [this author](https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-ner-with-bert-in-spark-nlp-874df20d1d77) says, i.e. `Peter NNP NNP I-PER` , `Parker NNP NNP I-PER` , etc... Is that correct?

Comment: Yep, but if you look closer, only the token and embeddings are used,

nerTagger = NerDLApproach()\
.setInputCols(["sentence", "token", "bert"])\